# Thinkscript Code to Draw a Line From Top of a Candle Body

Tags: thinkscript

I'm totally new to thinkscript. I'm trying to write some thinkscript code that will find highest green candle for the current trading day and draw a horizontal line from the topmost edge of that topmost green candle *body* to the end of the trading day. The current code I'm using draws a line from the topmost edge of that topmost green candle *wick* to the end of the trading day. But, again, I want the code to draw a horizontal line from the topmost edge of that topmost green candle *body* to the end of the trading day. Any suggestions?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
plot highLine = highestAll(if isNaN(close[-1])
                            then high(period = "Day")
                            else Double.NaN);
```